# How can I create a model/store for this data?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have a json file called data.json, and it contains the following json:

```
{
    "lists": [
        {
            "id":100,
            "title":"Grocery",
            "description":"Bryce & Madi",
            "items": [
                {
                    "name":"Milk",
                    "quantity":"2 Gallons",
                    "checked":false
                },
                {
                    "name":"Sugar",
                    "quantity":"2 Cups",
                    "checked":true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":200,
            "title":"Christmas",
            "description":"Our Christmas List",
            "items": [
                {
                    "name":"Shaver",
                    "quantity":"1",
                    "checked":false
                },
                {
                    "name":"Football",
                    "quantity":"1",
                    "checked":true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to create a model/store for this data to allow me to see just the main lists on the first page, then they can click a list and it will take them to a page that shows the `items` in that list as a list.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've been having problems wrapping my head around this structure. If it helps, here's what I have:

```
App.models.Lists = Ext.regModel("App.models.Lists", {
    hasMany: { model: App.models.List, name: 'list' },
    fields: [
        { name: "id", type: "int" },
        { name: "title", type: "string" },
        { name: "description", type: "string" },
        { name: "items", type: "auto" }
    ]
});

App.stores.Lists = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: "App.models.Lists",
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data.json',
        id: 'AppLocalStore',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'lists'
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        'load': function(store, records, options) {
            console.log(records);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should use [TreeStore](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore) and [NestedList](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.NestedList) for your needs.

"Seeing nested list example under the UserInterface on the [KitchenSink](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/)" may be helpful.